# Uploading image/pdf to slack channel using Mulesoft Slack Connector

Tags: slack, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4, mule-connector

i'm trying to use the mulesoft slack connector to upload a pdf file and a png file to a slack channel but i'm not able to configure the settings correctly to make this work. Has anyone been able to do so successfully? Here is my transform message just before the slack upload file connector:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/x-www-form-urlencoded
---
{
    "channels": "C03E4FWEQRY",
    "content": payload,
    "filename": "AdobePremierPro2021.pdf",
    "title": "AdobePremierPro2021",
    "filetype": "pdf"
}
```

It sends the file to the channel but all content is lost. The file comes across as a binary file that cannot be read.

Here is the XML snippet:

```
<flow name="upload-sub-flow" doc:id="1c8a2b29-5358-41bd-acd8-760676ddd86e" >
        <file:read doc:name="Read" doc:id="d4ba9476-4d83-47cd-8915-f1e8ef8e119e" config-ref="File_Config" path="/Users/aparkhe/AnypointStudio/1platform/slack-sys-api/src/main/resources/AdobePremierPro2021.pdf"/>
"]      <ee:transform doc:name="Transform Message" doc:id="72c36c3b-ce68-4c5d-8a0f-961f95a71569" >
            <ee:message >
                <ee:set-payload ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output application/x-www-form-urlencoded
---
{
    "channels": "C03E4FWEQRY",
    //"thread_ts": vars.SlackTS,
    "content":  payload,
    "filename": "AdobePremierPro2021.pdf",
    //"filename": "ArrivalPass.png",
    //"title": "AdobePremierPro2021",
    "filetype": "pdf"
}]]></ee:set-payload>
            </ee:message>
        </ee:transform>

        <slack:create-filesupload doc:name="Upload File" doc:id="08546a03-d746-42af-b50e-d45c11a5eb04" config-ref="Slack_Connector_Config"/>
    </flow>
```

Here is the POM dependency:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.connectors</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule4-slack-connector</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.12</version>
            <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: I was actually looking at a different version of the slack connector. Therefore I got confused. Can you also add the connector dependency from POM just to be sure. Also it will make it easier for everyone.

Comment: Just added the dependency to the post.

Comment: I tried it myself, but no luck. Tried to send both `multipart` and `www-urlencoded`. I will suggest to use either the [community version of slack](https://www.mulesoft.com/exchange/org.mule.connectors/mule-slack-connector/), or use HTTP request directly. I tried the community version and was able to send a PDF without any issue.

Comment: I dont think i can use the community version but i can use http. Infact i tried using http and was not able to get it to work either. please let me know if you can get the http request to work. i would greatly appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the slack connector is not enough matured yet, and is having problem with binary data. The [`file.upload`](https://api.slack.com/methods/files.upload) endpoint of Slack supports two MIME types, `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and other `multipart/form-data`. After checking the debug logs, it looks like the slack connector is only using the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` encoding, which is not the best usecase for sending binary data.

I will recommend you to use either of these options:

1. [slack connector community version](https://www.mulesoft.com/exchange/org.mule.connectors/mule-slack-connector/): It works great with similar configuration. You will not have to worry about the request structure as it will encapsulate everything. Also it uses `multipart/form-data` under the hood so you will not have any issues with PDF or PNG files. The usage is extremely simple so I will not add the details here. You will be able to understand it as soon as you drag the component.
2. Use the traditional `http:request` connector. The tricky part here is to create the [`multipart/form-data`](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dataweave-formats-multipart) payload. However you can use the [Multipart dataweave module](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dw-multipart) that will make it fairly simple.
   You will use [`Multipart::form`](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dw-multipart-functions-form) function to create the form, and pass an array of the 4 fields, that you were setting in your transform message, using [`Multipart:field`](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dw-multipart-functions-field) function.

   Your transform module will look like this

   ```js
   %dw 2.0
   import dw::module::Multipart
   output multipart/form-data
   ---
   Multipart::form([
     Multipart::field("channels","#testing"),
     Multipart::field("filename","AdobePremierPro2021"),
     Multipart::field("filetype","pdf"),
     Multipart::field("file",payload, "application/pdf", "AdobePremierPro2021.pdf"),
   ])
   ```

   *The payload here will be the output of the `file:read` operation*

Comment: This worked!!!! I cannot tell you how many hours i spent chasing this. Thank you so much @Harshank