# Mule 4- slack Mulesoft connector creating corrupted xlsx file (which contains multiple sheets) to slack channel with upload file operational scope

Tags: slack, slack-api, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

i was trying to upload xlsx file which contains multiple sheets to slack channel with the below is the code snippet

```
        <ee:transform doc:name="Transform Message" doc:id="568e7e17-1177-4dac-9a6f-985c45827215">
            <ee:message>
                <ee:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output application/x-www-form-urlencoded
---
{
    "channels": "#notification-accelerator",
   "content":write(payload, "application/xlsx") ,
    "filename": vars.filename ,
    "title": vars.filename,
    "filetype": "xlsx "
}]]></ee:set-payload>
            </ee:message>
        </ee:transform>
<slack:create-filesupload doc:name="Upload File" doc:id="d6771237-59c3-401c-a8d6-9c8f0a61ba58" config-ref="Slack_Connector_Config" />
```

here i was sending this dwl transformed payload to slack to upload file, **xlsx file was getting generated in slack channel as corrupted file.same data in other formats like json or txt ,those files are able access/view to the data.** same xlsx file payload  i was sending it mailbox through smtp as an attachment,it was creating in correct format. But with Slack connector, files which contains xlsx data ,those are getting corrupt/not able  to view the data.

Slack connector dependency from pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mulesoft.connectors</groupId>
    <artifactId>mule4-slack-connector</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.16</version>
    <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uploading image/pdf to slack channel using Mulesoft Slack Connector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72349522/uploading-image-pdf-to-slack-channel-using-mulesoft-slack-connector)